# How to create a new instance each time method is called with different parameters?

Tags: java, methods, timer, instance

in my application i have to use external library, to reduce excessive code i want to create a method "startDelay" that each time it is called wil create a new timer and keeps running even when the method is called again with different parameters.

but it seems that when im calling the method it resets and doesnt create a new timer.

for example:

i have a 5s delay and a 10s delay. so a few seconds after the 5s one is started i want to start the other 10s delay. (create a new one) the 5s delay will not finish its original count and just start over again with the new timer. The running timers wont finish when a new call is made.

how can i solve this? thank you in advance!

```
public class BIhcsTestModule extends BComponent implements Runnable {
 
    Clock.Ticket[] delayTimer = new Clock.Ticket[10];
    int count = 0;

    public void run() {System.out.println("Source BProgram did not 
    override run(). Exiting thread.");
}
    //Main
     public void doExecute() throws Exception {
     try {
        if (getBBool_1()) {
            startDelay(getTTime_1(), action1, 21);
        }
        if (getBBool_2()) {
            startDelay(getTTime_2(), action2, 22);
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}           
        
    public void startDelay(BRelTime delayTime, String 
    actionToTrigger, Integer newStatus) {
        //reset count
        if (count >= delayTimer.length) {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (count < delayTimer.length) {
        
            if (delayTimer[count] != null) {
                delayTimer[count].cancel();
                delayTimer[count] = null;
            }

            //if time is set
            if (delayTime.getSeconds() > 0) {
                this.delayTimer[count] = Clock.schedule(this.getComponent(), delayTime, this.getComponent().getAction(actionToTrigger), (BValue) new BStatusNumeric(newStatus));
            }
        } else {
            setDebugLine("t not >0");
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*startDelay* method seems good in your code. Check you are using same *BIhcsTestModule* instance for all *startDelay* method calls.

Comment: ive have edited the code in my post to show the call i make to startDelay. its from within the same instance of BIhcsTestModule. is this ok?

Comment: This should work for your need since both method calls act on the same BIhcsTestModule instance. however you can call the startdelay outside the BIhcsTestModule class, 2 times with same instance like `BIhcsTestModule instance = new BIhcsTestModule(); instance.startDelay(..); instance.startDelay(..);`  and avoid extra method call doExecute